# Simple Comparing of two texts in R

Tags: r, comparison

I want to compare two texts to similarity, therefore i need a simple function to list clearly and chronologically the words and phrases occurring in both texts. these words/sentences should be highlighted or underlined for better visualization)

on the base of @joris Meys ideas, i added an array to divide text into sentences and subordinate sentences.

this is how it looks like:

```
  textparts <- function (text){
  textparts <- c("\\,", "\\.")
  i <- 1
  while(i<=length(textparts)){
        text <- unlist(strsplit(text, textparts[i]))
        i <- i+1
  }
  return (text)
}

textparts1 <- textparts("This is a complete sentence, whereas this is a dependent clause. This thing works.")
textparts2 <- textparts("This could be a sentence, whereas this is a dependent clause. Plagiarism is not cool. This thing works.")

  commonWords <- intersect(textparts1, textparts2)
  commonWords <- paste("\\<(",commonWords,")\\>",sep="")


  for(x in commonWords){
    textparts1 <- gsub(x, "\\1*", textparts1,ignore.case=TRUE)
    textparts2 <- gsub(x, "\\1*", textparts2,ignore.case=TRUE)
  }
  return(list(textparts1,textparts2))
```

However, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

I WOULD like to have results like these:

```
>   return(list(textparts1,textparts2))
[[1]]
[1] "This is a complete sentence"         " whereas this is a dependent clause*" " This thing works*"                  

[[2]]
[1] "This could be a sentence"            " whereas this is a dependent clause*" " Plagiarism is not cool"             " This thing works*"
```

whereas i get none results.

Comment: Have a look at the CRAN taskview for natural language processing for inspiration: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html

Comment: thx, i know about this site. There is a sentence detector, which might be useful for me, but there is none sentence-compared highlighting what i'm looking for

Comment: hehe, now you make it confusing for the people. You can add comments if a solution is not what you're looking for, but you shouldn't change the content of your question. This is a completely different question. Second, you're not coding C, you're coding R. That while() construct is hideous. do `for(i in textparts)` and drop all the rest. And then you should take a look at what goes on. You might have spaces here and there, messing up your result. You might have differences uppercase-lowercase. Check the help files and check your intermediate results, and you'll solve it.

Answer (score 7):

There are some problems with the answer of @Chase :

- differences in capitalization are not taken into account
- interpunction can mess up results
- if there is more than one word similar, then you get a lot of warnings due to the gsub call.

Based on his idea, there is the following solution that makes use of `tolower()` and some nice functionalities of regular expressions :

```
compareSentences <- function(sentence1, sentence2) {
  # split everything on "not a word" and put all to lowercase
  x1 <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(sentence1, "\\W")))
  x2 <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(sentence2, "\\W")))

  commonWords <- intersect(x1, x2)
  #add word beginning and ending and put words between ()
  # to allow for match referencing in gsub
  commonWords <- paste("\\<(",commonWords,")\\>",sep="")


  for(x in commonWords){ 
    # replace the match by the match with star added
    sentence1 <- gsub(x, "\\1*", sentence1,ignore.case=TRUE)
    sentence2 <- gsub(x, "\\1*", sentence2,ignore.case=TRUE)
  }
  return(list(sentence1,sentence2))      
}
```

This gives following result :

```
text1 <- "This is a test. Weather is fine"
text2 <- "This text is a test. This weather is fine. This blabalba This "

compareSentences(text1,text2)
[[1]]
[1] "This* is* a* test*. Weather* is* fine*"

[[2]]
[1] "This* text is* a* test*. This* weather* is* fine*. This* blabalba This* "
```

Comment: great thanks. 1 more question: this is very useful for 1 or two sentences. i would like to analyze texts with 10-15 sentences. In other words, it would be better to search for trigrams.

Comment: @digitalaxp : you have all the building blocks. See `?regex` and `?strsplit` for example. This isn't difficult, but SO is not hire-a-coder-for-free.

Comment: @joris-meys sorry, my fault! anyway, i tried it on my own and edited my first post.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure that there are far more robust functions on the natural language processing page, but here's one solution using `intersect()` to find the common words. The approach is to read in the two sentences, identify the common words and `gsub()` them with a combination of the word and a moniker of our choice. Here I chose to use `*`, but you could easily change that, or add something else.

```
sent1 <- "I shot the sheriff."
sent2 <- "Dick Cheney shot a man."

compareSentences <- function(sentence1, sentence2) {
  sentence1 <- unlist(strsplit(sentence1, " "))
  sentence2 <- unlist(strsplit(sentence2, " "))

  commonWords <- intersect(sentence1, sentence2)

  return(list(
      sentence1 = paste(gsub(commonWords, paste(commonWords, "*", sep = ""), sentence1), collapse = " ")
    , sentence2 = paste(gsub(commonWords, paste(commonWords, "*", sep = ""), sentence2), collapse = " ")
    ))
}

> compareSentences(sent1, sent2)
$sentence1
[1] "I shot* the sheriff."

$sentence2
[1] "Dick Cheney shot* a man."
```

Comment: Well, the person Cheney shot was technically a lawyer.

Comment: +1 for intersect. I've taken your idea and polished it a bit for a more general solution.